# Javascript Prevent Default - Prevent Swipe Back Only

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, polymer

On a web app that I am working on, one of my elements is pretty large (a table), and thus, reaches near the edges of the iphone's screen.

When a user touchmoves on the element, the user can select various things that appear within the table.  When the user's finger is in the table, I prevent all default touch actions.  However, I do not prevent default touch actions universally on the page because I want the user to still be able to scroll and zoom normally when outside the element.

The problem I am facing is that if the User moves just a little bit outside the element while engaged in a touchmove, the user often ends up swiping back.

Like I said, I do not want to prevent default universally because scroll and zoom are important to me on this particular page.  Is there a way to prevent back swipe only using jquery, polymer, javascript, or some combination of all three?

Comment: Will the user get confused(ux issue?) if the back swipe that works for all the pages is not working when this particular page is loaded?

Comment: Thats a good point, that I hadn't considered.  My gut says that even if it is confusing, the frustration of accidentally going back trumps that concern.  Moreover, the site has iphone like back buttons that users can use if they do get confused by the lack of swipe back functionality.

Comment: I would suggest you keep the default behavior, but since this is a pressing problem, may be you can add a confirm dialog to window.onbeforeunload, which can save the accidental data loss.

Comment: Thanks.  That was my plan B.